# PHP Mysql Forum User Creation Script doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

My code doesn't work, nor it gives me any errors, so the code is right, but still doesn't work.
The code aims to look up for the entered data of a HTML form and, if the entered values are not stored on the database, creating them(the new user).

```
 <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('SECURE', true);
require_once('_connecting.php');


 include "_head.php";



if(isset($_POST["send"]))
{
$username = $_POST["user_name"];
$mail=$_POST["user_email"];

$passwort = $_POST["user_password"];

$passwort2 = $_POST["user_password2"];





if(strlen($passwort)<6||$passwort!=$passwort2)
   {
   echo "Eingabefehler. Bitte alle Felder korekt ausf&uuml;llen. <a href=\"signup.php\">Zur&uuml;ck</a>";







       }

else


{

$check = ("SELECT Count(*) FROM user WHERE user_email ='$mail'");




$mysqli->query($check);


if ($check > 1) {
   echo "Schon vorhanden";

   exit();


} else {



$send="INSERT INTO user (user_name, user_email,user_password) VALUES ('$username','$passwort','$mail')";



$mysqli->query($send);








}




}}






?>






























    <h1>
    Registriere dich jetzt, um alle Funktionen des Forums in vollem Umfang genie&szlig;en zu k&ouml;nnen.

    </h1>
    <h1 id="yellowh1">
    Du wirst es nicht bereuen - Es warten viele spannende Dinge auf dich.





    </h1>




<form action="signup.php" method="post">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="" required="required" placeholder="Nutzername" maxlength="255" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="email" name="user_email" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['user_email']) ? $_POST['user_email'] : ''; ?>" required="required" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" maxlength="255" />
<br><br>
<input type="password" name="user_password" required="required" placeholder="Passwort" maxlength="50" />
<input type="password" name="user_password2" required="required" placeholder="Passwort erneut eingeben" maxlength="50" />
<br><br>




<input type="submit" value="Abschicken" name="send">
</form>

  <?php include "_footer.php";?>
```

Comment: do double check when writing code `$_POSST`. Your query depends on that one. `WHERE user_email ='$mail'` - `$mail=$_POSST["user_email"];`

Comment: *"my code doesn't work,nor it gives me any errors"* - that's because you're not checking for errors, anywhere. Either on PHP or the query. *"so the code is right, but still doesn't work."* - that's a contradictory statement.

Comment: Change $mail=$_POSST["user_email"]; to $mail=$_POST["user_email"];

Comment: [`Notice: Undefined variable: _POSST in...` - *I knew that's what the notice would be.*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @MatHatrik that's only *one* of the problems here.

Comment: `$mysqli->query->execute` seems kind of strange.

Comment: @Don'tPanic ugh.. good catch. I didn't see that one. I'll have to edit my answer, and give kudos to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

```
$mail=$_POSST["user_email"];
```

Firstly, there is a typo in there and you must remove one of the `S`'s. It's a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Having error reporting would have signaled:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _POSST in...

As I stated in comments, your query depends on it. `WHERE user_email ='$mail'` and you're not checking for errors anywhere.

- `VALUES ('$username','$passwort','$mail')` that will also fail because of the typo in `$_POSST`.

Then you have `value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>"` for the `name="user_email"` input, which will also throw the following notice in the input field itself, as soon as you hit the submit button:

> Notice:  Undefined variable: user_email in...

Therefore, you need to use a ternary operator:

```
value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['user_email']) ? $_POST['user_email'] : ''; ?>"
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Final notes:

Since the MySQL API to connect with is unknown (to me), make sure that you are in fact using `mysqli_` to connect with, and not another one that is different. Different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.

- Use the same API from connection to query.
- https://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

As stated in comments and kudos to "**Don't Panic**":

> *$mysqli->query->execute seems kind of strange. –  Don't Panic*

This method of querying `$mysqli->query->execute(...)` is used for prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Those need to be modified as just `$mysqli->query(...)`

- As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I changed posst to post, but still doesnt work.. Ill check your codes,when im at home again :) THX :) i hope it will work like this

Comment: ive changed my code to what you told me to, but  it still doesn't work nor i get some errors... can you please take a look on my edited script ?I edited my question, so that now there is my "new" code.

Comment: Cloded# i found the solution, i changed it to what the manuel reads

Comment: @Needforbleed that's great, glad to hear it and thanks for the update, *cheers*